# why some websites change default font size to 14px

Tags: css, github, fonts, standards

I saw many sites change default font size from 16px to 14px
like
https://opensea.io
and
https://github.com

What is reason behind this ?
Is it new standard for webdesign?

Comment: 0. you can manually change the CSS var with dev tools... 1. if it is your website you can also change it on your website by adding a lower/bigger value to the parent element (and use "em" CSS units based on that), 2. another thing is they tried to create an "issue" on their GitHub profile ("GitHub desktop" in this case) but they suggest to change it from settings/preferences https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3543 (because in Chinese is not readable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 16px has been chosen for its good ratio with `rem` or `em`.
This is why it is mostly used, but this not a standard, even browser can have different font-size default.

If you change it to 14px it will be probably to fit better with the proportion of your elements, on your page.
But basically change it does not really make sens except if you want to have less size different but it does not change much.

16px:

```css
/*
10px = 0.625rem
12px = 0.75rem
14px = 0.875rem
16px = 1rem (base)
18px = 1.125rem
20px = 1.25rem
24px = 1.5rem
30px = 1.875rem
32px = 2rem
*/
```

14px:

```css
/*
10.5px    = 0.75rem
12.25px   = 0.875rem
14px      = 1rem (base)
15.75px   = 1.125rem
17.5px    = 1.25rem
21px      = 1.5rem
*/
```